# Why is this line in my url file for django giving me a syntax error?

Tags: django, url, syntax

```
url(r'^website/', include('website.urls')),
```

This line is giving me a syntax error. When I remove it, the error goes away. Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: No aparent error, maybe the previous line should be ended by comma and lacks it?

Comment: Maybe provide more context of the url line?

Comment: Posting full urlpatterns will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the last line, it doesn't require comma, like this example :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^report_builder/', include('report_builder.urls'))
]
```

Comment: It's not required, but certainly recommended.